# Android Studio missing drawable Folder

Tags: android-studio, directory, drawable

I've been trying to import an icon into drawable folder, then I found that drawable folders are missing any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android Studio is automatically creating projects with `mipmap` folder and putting the icons on it. So you simply have to create the `drawable` folder into `res`.